# Is this sentence about programming practice correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, idiomatic-language

I'm writing a company guide about the programming interface that is created. English is not my native language and I am having difficulties creating a statement.

> It is strongly advised **to use the UoM as good practice method** when working with Autodesk Inventor value conversion operations and more.

UoM is short for Units of Measure, defined earlier in the guide.

I'm getting the feeling that the section about using UoM as "good practice" is not read easy but forced.

Comment: Hi, i'm new to SE is there a place where I can see a good constructive post that I can base my question on?

Comment: There is some advice on the meta site in the discussion [Please, everyone… details. Please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please)  We work together to try to make questions and answers better, so just do the best you can and other folks will try to help by editing or asking for clarification. If you have questions about how the site works, you will be able to post a question on [meta] and join us in [chat] once you get [a little bit of reputation](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). I've up-voted so you can participate in meta now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[best practice](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/best-practice) is defined as **a working method or set of working methods that is officially accepted as being the best to use in a particular business or industry, usually described formally and in detail**. In some business areas (particularly medicine), the term **good practice** is also used.

I have adapted your sentence to make it more understandable to lay people:

> It is strongly advised to use a dictionary as good practice method when writing.

Here are four more conventional ways of expressing this advice:

> Best/good practice is to use a dictionary when writing.
>   It is strongly advised to use a dictionary when writing.
>   Using a dictionary when writing is recommended as good practice
>   When writing, using a dictionary is recommended as good practice

- it's overkill to use both **good/best practice** and **it is strongly advised**.
- **good practice** and **best practice** are normally used on its own, without **method**.

For more examples of usage of the expression **good practice**, check [this link](https://www.google.com.eg/search?q=%22good%20practice%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr&ei=MItFWOmrFcWZsgGx1ae4Cg).

Answer (score -1):

You could go with "as a good practice".
By using the article "a" you tend not to force the decision but give it as one of the things that can be used as a best practice to work with Autodesk Inventor value conversion etc. Moreover you can omit the word method because it might be understood that the UoM is a method.(in programming terms) .

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain *why* this is correct. Answers without explanation don't teach the pattern of English language well.

Comment: Your edits have much improved your answer - I think it would be even better if you wrote out the entire sentence to show how your suggestions work together.

Answer (score -1):

There is a set phrase "best practice" which refers to the consensus opinion within an industry or organization regarding the optimal way to do something.

> When working with Autodesk Inventor, best practice is to use the UoM
>   defined earlier in this guide.

Comment: I think you should say "the best practice"

Comment: "the best practice" is not "best practice", sorry. You are mistaken. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22best%20practice%20within%20the%20industry%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: rebuttal: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22best%20practice%20within%20the%20industry%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en#lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&q=%22the+best+practice+within+the+industry%22

Comment: FYI, I'm a native speaker and your sentence as such sounds odd without the article. If you look at some of the sentences in your google link, they are using "best practice" is a slightly different use, e.g "promoting best practice" which is not using "best practice" as a specific instance noun the way your sentence does

Comment: When it is used as a set phrase/term of trade,  "best practice" is not accompanied by the article, just as "good practice" is often used without an article:  "It's good practice to look before you leap."

Comment: "It's good practice to..." Yes, but not necessarily "Good practice is..."; "A good practice is..."

Comment: I've worked in programming for ~6 years; we would use "the best practice in this context" all the time.

Comment: I'm responding to your claim that "it sounds odd without the article".  Both forms are idiomatic. Without the article, it's a "term of trade" or a set phrase. With the article, well, then it's just English.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49614/discussion-between-eques-and-tromano).